# How to organise an SQL Database Table?

Tags: php, sql, database

I am developing a blog and would like to be able to organise the data stored in my database so that the most recent rows of data are displayed at the top of the table and go further back in time the further down you scroll, is there any way to do this through PHP or SQL?

Thanks in advance,

EDIT: Question answered, thanks - I had already developed the blog but decided to make some changes to incorporate learning SQL

Comment: If you're stuck on this, you will have a hard time developing a blog. Have you considered using WordPress or something like it?

Answer (score 2):

No. Most databases don't allow you to sort rows yourself. They sort it based on available space. To get rows in a specific order, use `ORDER BY` in an SQL query. Using `ORDER BY`, you can sort the result when retrieving the data *from* the database.